# T-SQL SELECT Statment to Exclude Text Between ( And ) Without Update or Variables

Tags: t-sql

I'm wondering if this is possible, I have a messy set of first name data to work with, and it's shared by other applications so I don't want to run any update statements.  But the data will sometime include an AKA such as:

Robert (AKA Bob)

And I am trying to get a clean data where it just says "Robert".

One way I thought of is to use a temp table then CHARINDEX for ( and ) then REPLACE what's between ( and ).  This seems like a long winded way to do this.

Is there a smarter way?

EDIT: More examples of the data hell. Sometimes the parenthesis comes in the front or mixed up such as:

(Bill) William

Richard (Dick) Jr.

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
FirstName = case when charindex('(AKA', FirstName) = 0 
                 then FirstName 
                 else substring(FirstName, 1, charindex('(AKA', FirstName)) end
```

Comment: Pieter, thank you for the input.  I included additional examples where the parenthesis comes in front and some with the AKA between.

Answer (score 0):

If the noisy string pattern is unpredictable, better to use SQL CLR TVF(table value function), utilize C# code regex. Taking an xml as input parameter, which includes data you need to process, return a table with data processed.

Answer (score -1):

Pieter got the ball rolling for me!  Thank you for getting me started on the right track!

```
 SELECT
 CASE WHEN FirstName like '%)%'
 THEN REPLACE(FirstName,
 SUBSTRING(FirstName,CHARINDEX('(',FirstName),CHARINDEX(')',FirstName)-CHARINDEX('(',FirstName)+1),'')
 ELSE FirstName END
```